# First JBoss Example Crashing (jbpm 6.0, AS7, Windows 7)

Tags: java, windows, windows-7, jboss, jboss7.x

I've installed and started AS7 with Ant-- ant install.demo + ant start.demo.  Everything starts fine -- H2 database, JBOSS, and Eclipse.

Following this tutorial video -->

I've imported the Java evaluation project into Eclipse.  When I try Debug As--> Java Application, it crashes with:

"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument is not of type EntityManagerFactory."

I added a "main" method as there was none in the class:

```
 public static void main(String args[]) 
 {     ProcessTest pt = new ProcessTest();    
       pt.testEvaluationProcess();      
 }
```

Please advise.

-TU

Answer (score 0):

I acquired the necessary information to get this going.  It turns out this should be run as a JUnit test and not as a Java application.  Works!